# Custom desktop environment for Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome-panel, desktop-environments, debian, cinnamon

I like Unity a lot for its gorgeous `dash and panel look`, the `global menu and HUD`, the `super+# shortcuts` and that's it. I really hate it for the stupid launcher and its general inflexibility compared to almost every other DE (including Windows) as probably most of us do.
I would much rather have `cinnamon`'s or `mate`'s modularity but I can't switch to these because I just cannot do without Unity's best features and `Compiz` as far as I know is unrivalled.

So my question is how can I have some sort of `Unity + cinnamon`? Can I tweak Unity into looking more like cinnamon? Are there any tools out there to replace the panel or even add an extra panel layer on top of it? So far I've been doing just that to some extent, using `tint2` (amazing tool btw) on top of the Unity panel since the launcher is no good :
[image: unity + tint2]

I'd also like rock solid stability so I was wondering if in that regard installing `Debian Stable + Unity + tint2 + whatever-you-can-suggest` would be better than the `12.04 Ubuntu` I have right now. If it is I won't hesitate, I don't mind tweaking and learning.

And if by miracle you could get me Compiz awesomeness and Unity's good features without these 2, I'd immediately go for it, e.g. I hear `KDE` can emulate almost any desktop with enough tweak.

I ask this question on AskUbuntu because I feel many Ubuntu users are frustrated with this dilemma as well and as such are really likely to have looked into that before I did, if not feel free to redirect. Thank you.